# Add two lines every four lines between patterns - SED

Tags: sed

I'm needing some help with Sed. I'm using it on Windows and Mac OSX. I need to Sed to add a

```
</tr>
<tr>
```

every 4 lines, after the first `<tr>` found, and stop doing it on `</tr>`

i Just can't find a way to doing this. 
Every file will have up to 20 tables, so i need to do it automatically...

changing from this

```
<div class="titulo"> TERMINAL CAPAO DA IMBUIA</div>
<div class="dataedia">
Válido a partir de: 30/07/2012 - 
DIA ÚTIL</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>05:50</td>
<td>05:58</td>
<td>06:04</td>
<td>06:08</td>
<td>06:12</td>
<td>06:15</td>
<td>06:17</td>
<td>06:20</td>
<td>06:22</td>
<td>06:25</td>
<td>06:27</td>
<td>06:30</td>
<td>06:32</td>
<td>06:35</td>
<td>06:37</td>
<td>06:39</td>
<td>06:42</td>
<td>06:44</td>
<td>06:47</td>
<td>06:49</td>
<td>06:52</td>
<td>06:54</td>
<td>06:57</td>
<td>06:59</td>
<td>07:01</td>
<td>07:04</td>
<td>07:06</td>
<td>07:09</td>
<td>07:11</td>
<td>07:14</td>
<td>07:16</td>
<td>07:18</td>
<td>07:21</td>
<td>07:23</td>
<td>07:26</td>
<td>07:28</td>
<td>07:31</td>
<td>07:33</td>
<td>07:36</td>
<td>07:38</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div class="titulo"> TERMINAL CAPAO DA IMBUIA</div>
<div class="dataedia">
Válido a partir de: 30/07/2012 - 
DIA ÚTIL</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>05:50</td>
<td>05:58</td>
<td>06:04</td>
<td>06:08</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:12</td>
<td>06:15</td>
<td>06:17</td>
<td>06:20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:22</td>
<td>06:25</td>
<td>06:27</td>
<td>06:30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:32</td>
<td>06:35</td>
<td>06:37</td>
<td>06:39</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:42</td>
<td>06:44</td>
<td>06:47</td>
<td>06:49</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:52</td>
<td>06:54</td>
<td>06:57</td>
<td>06:59</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:01</td>
<td>07:04</td>
<td>07:06</td>
<td>07:09</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:11</td>
<td>07:14</td>
<td>07:16</td>
<td>07:18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:21</td>
<td>07:23</td>
<td>07:26</td>
<td>07:28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:31</td>
<td>07:33</td>
<td>07:36</td>
<td>07:38</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Is it possible with `sed`? If not, what tool should i use?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like the idea of using `sed` to handle HTML code. Said that, try with this:

Content of `script.sed`:

```
## For every line between '<tr>' and '</tr>' do ...
/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/ {

    ## Omit range edges.
    /<\/\?tr>/ b;

    ## Append '<td>...</td>' to Hold Space (HS).
    H;  

    ## Get HS to Pattern Space (PS) to work with it.
    x;  

    ## If there are at least four newline characters means that exists four
    ## '<td>' tags too, so add a '<tr>' before them and a '</tr>' after them,
    ## print, and delete them (already processed).
    /\(\n[^\n]*\)\{4\}/ {
        s/^\(\n\)/<tr>\1/;
        s/$/\n<\/tr>/;
        p   
        s/^.*$//;
    }   

    ## Save the '<td>'s to HS again and read next line.
    x;  
    b;  
}

## Print all lines out of the range.
p;
```

Assuming `infile` with the data posted in the question, run the script like:

```
sed -nf script.sed infile
```

That yields:

```
<div class="titulo"> TERMINAL CAPAO DA IMBUIA</div>
<div class="dataedia">
Válido a partir de: 30/07/2012 - 
DIA ÚTIL</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>05:50</td>
<td>05:58</td>
<td>06:04</td>
<td>06:08</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:12</td>
<td>06:15</td>
<td>06:17</td>
<td>06:20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:22</td>
<td>06:25</td>
<td>06:27</td>
<td>06:30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:32</td>
<td>06:35</td>
<td>06:37</td>
<td>06:39</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:42</td>
<td>06:44</td>
<td>06:47</td>
<td>06:49</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:52</td>
<td>06:54</td>
<td>06:57</td>
<td>06:59</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:01</td>
<td>07:04</td>
<td>07:06</td>
<td>07:09</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:11</td>
<td>07:14</td>
<td>07:16</td>
<td>07:18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:21</td>
<td>07:23</td>
<td>07:26</td>
<td>07:28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:31</td>
<td>07:33</td>
<td>07:36</td>
<td>07:38</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This wont work if i have a small file... any way to make it ignore it, or make it search for <table> and </table> instead of <tr> and </tr>?

Answer (score 1):

try `awk`

```
awk '{print}; /<td>/ && ++i==4 {print "</tr>\n<tr>"; i=0}' file
```

- print the line
- if it's a `<td>` then increase `i`
- if `i` is `4` print `</tr><tr>` and reset `i`

---

Testing with given input the desired output is returned,
with the only "problem" that an extra `<tr></tr>` appears at the end of the list. 
This is fixable but I'm running out of time here.
When I get back I can look into it if you think it is needed.

*... part of the end of the result file*

```
<td>07:26</td>
<td>07:28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:31</td>
<td>07:33</td>
<td>07:36</td>
<td>07:38</td>
</tr>
<tr>             <-- extra <tr></tr> here
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll look into awk... Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 1):

you can try with regular expressions. You can test following expression on:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Catch expression:

```
?</td>.<td>.*?</td>.<td>.*?</td>.<td>.*?</td>)(?!.</tr>)
```

Replace expression:

```
$1\n</tr>\n<tr>
```

Flags checked:

```
global, ignorecase, dotall
```

Result:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>05:50</td>
<td>05:58</td>
<td>06:04</td>
<td>06:08</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:12</td>
<td>06:15</td>
<td>06:17</td>
<td>06:20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:22</td>
<td>06:25</td>
<td>06:27</td>
<td>06:30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:32</td>
<td>06:35</td>
<td>06:37</td>
<td>06:39</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:42</td>
<td>06:44</td>
<td>06:47</td>
<td>06:49</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>06:52</td>
<td>06:54</td>
<td>06:57</td>
<td>06:59</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:01</td>
<td>07:04</td>
<td>07:06</td>
<td>07:09</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:11</td>
<td>07:14</td>
<td>07:16</td>
<td>07:18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:21</td>
<td>07:23</td>
<td>07:26</td>
<td>07:28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>07:31</td>
<td>07:33</td>
<td>07:36</td>
<td>07:38</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

You can use editor like Notepad++ for batch replace on many files at once (syntax will be little different).

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution, still using regular expression instead of parsing HTML:

```
perl -pe '
    undef $inside if m{</tr>};
    if ($inside and ($. % 4) == $tr_line) {
        print "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    }
    $inside = 1 if defined $tr_line;
    $tr_line = ($. + 1) % 4 if /<tr>/;
    ' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '\!<td>!,\!</table!{N;N;N;i\
</tr>\
<tr>
}' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML/XSH2):

```
open :F html file ;                                                   # Open as html.
while //table/tr[count(td)>4] wrap :U position()=8 tr //table/tr/td ; # Wrap four td's into a tr.
xmove :r //table/tr/tr before .. ;                                    # Unwrap the extra tr.
remove //table/tr[last()] ;                                           # Remove the extra tr.
```